# How do you delete an image from a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to remove/delete an image that I inserted into a google sheet.
I used the code:

sheet.insertImage(url,col,row);

to insert the image.  But, I want to remove the image later in the code and insert a different image. or not have an image at all.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
      // Deletes all images in sheet
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your Tab Name");
      var images = sheet.getImages();
      images.map(function(img){img.remove();});
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code to remove your image

```
    function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('B7:G7').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and changed the range to the range where the image was inserted. But, this did not work.

Answer (score -1):

In my testing, inserting a different image, in the the same cell, simply stacks the new image over the top of the old image.

```
sheet.insertImage('http://somewhere.com/images/image1.png',col,row);
sheet.insertImage('http://somewhere.com/images/image2.png',col,row);
```

I had hoped to effectively 'remove' image1 by substituting a blank(transparent) image2. One can cover up image1 with some other opaque image. ('mask', 'overlay', 'overlap' 'conceal', 'hide')

[overlapped images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTtl8.png)
In my experience, theCell.clearContent() does not affect the image but will clear other cell contents.